# É possivel abrir um app no ios sem que este app tenha URLScheme ?

Tags: ios, iphone

Eu queria checar se está instalado ou não também. Pelas minhas pesquisar tudo leva a crer que não é possivel sem o url scheme, mas ví muitas perguntas sem respostas aqui.

Comment: A resposta direta para esta pergunta é que realmente não é possível. Agora, você pode explicar a sua necessidade, pois pode haver outra solução ou só afirmar mesmo que esta seria a única forma, infelizmente.

Comment: Minha necessidade, tenho um app que vai mostrar uma area de "Apps uteis" de orgaos parceiros, que apesar de serem parceiros não vão modificar, alterar ou incluir nada em seus apps já feitos. Eu vou alem de redirecionar pra pagina da loja, gostaria quando possivel verificar se o app esta instalado e abri-lo diretamente (nao vou executaro ou mandar nada pra ele, so abrir)